# webpack + express.js doesn't load bundle.js

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack

I'm looknig to create an app with node + express js as backend and react + webpack as front end, but I'm still getting errors and the bundle.js doesn't load. This is how my folders looks like: In the root directory I have the node_modules, src folder that containst main.js and compoenents subfolder, package.json and wepback config.js. This is how my root folder looks like:

[image]

//// webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: './src',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        inline: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['react','es2015']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

//server.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
    const webpackMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
    const app = express();
    const compiler = webpack(config);

    const PORT = 3000 || process.env.port;

    app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
        noInfo: false,
        quiet: false,
        lazy: true,
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: true
        },
        publicPath: "/assets/",  
        index: "index.html",
        headers: { "X-Custom-Header": "yes" },
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
        reporter: null,
        serverSideRender: false,
    }));

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html');

});

app.listen(PORT)
```

///index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script src='bundle.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.8.js"></script>
</html>
```

///main.js

```
import App from './components/App';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

///console error

```
reporter: null,
^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

All I need is to get express working with react and webpack, I'm kinda new to webpack..

Comment: This has nothing to do with Webpack, but with a simple missing comma. The error tells you where to look.

Comment: Why are u saying this? I'm using webpack for react side.., just wanna make express js render webpack which compiles main js into bundle js

Comment: I'm saying that the error you're getting isn't related to Webpack, the code in `server.js` has a syntax error. The error message tells you where.

Comment: That's true, but I made some modifications to server.js, the console doesn't throw erros, but the bundle.js file still doesn't load..

Comment: the line `const PORT = 3000 || process.env.port;` in server.js is senseless. It should be `const PORT = process.env.port || 3000;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middleware configuration uses `/assets/` as `publicPath`, but you're not setting a public path in your Webpack configuration.

I would suggest setting `publicPath` in `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
...

output: {
  path       : path.resolve('./src'), // always use absolute paths
  filename   : 'bundle.js',
  publicPath : '/assets/'
}
```

And reuse its value for the middleware configuration:

```
app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath : config.output.publicPath,
  ...
});
```

Lastly, make sure the URL in your HTML is pointing to the correct URL:

```
<script src='/assets/bundle.js'></script>
```